# How to set a priority for the execution of the program in source code?

Tags: c++, windows

I wrote the following code, that must do search of all possible combinations of two digits in a string whose length is specified:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main ()
{   
    using namespace std;
    cout<<"Enter length of array"<<endl;
    int size;
    cin>>size;
    int * ps=new int [size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        ps[i]=3;
    int k=4;
    SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    while (k>=0)
    {
        for (int bi=0; bi<size; bi++)
            std::cout<<ps[bi];
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        int i=size-1;
        if (ps[i]==3)
        {
            ps[i]=4;
            continue;
        }
        if (ps[i]==4)
        {
            while (ps[i]==4)
            {
                ps[i]=3;
                --i;
            }
            ps[i]=4;
            if (i<k)
                k--;

        }

    }
}
```

When programm was executing on Windows 7, I saw that load of CPU is only 10-15%, in order to make my code worked faster, i decided to change priority of my programm to High. But when i did it there was no increase in work and load of CPU  stayed the same. Why CPU load doesn't change? Incorrect statement `SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS);`? Or this code cannot work faster?

Comment: Windows or Linux or OSX or Solaris or ....?

Comment: You don't, by any chance, have a system with, say, 8 cores? A single threaded application won't get more than 12.5% on an 8 core system, and no more than 25% in a 4 core system.

Comment: @MatsPetersson But I have only 2 cores.

Comment: Then see RedX's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your CPU is not working at it's full capacity it means that your application is not capable of using it because of causes like I/O, sleeps, memory or other device throughtput capabilties.

Most probably, however, it means that **your CPU has 2+ cores and your application is single-threaded**. In this case you have to go through the process of paralellizing your application, which is often neither simple nor fast.

In case of the code you posted, the most time consuming operation is actually (most probably) printing the results. Remove the `cout` code and see for yourself how fast the code will work.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the priority of your programm won't help much.

What you need to do is to remove the `cout` from your calculations. Store your computations and output them afterwards.

As others have noted it might also be that you use a multi-core machine. Anyway removing any output from your computation loop is always a first step to use 100% of your machines computation power for that and not waste cycles on output.

```
std::vector<int> results;
results.reserve(1000); // this should ideally match the number of results you expect

while (k>=0)
{
    for (int bi=0; bi<size; bi++){
        results.push_back(ps[bi]);
    }
    int i=size-1;
    if (ps[i]==3)
    {
        ps[i]=4;
        continue;
    }
    if (ps[i]==4)
    {
        while (ps[i]==4)
        {
            ps[i]=3;
            --i;
        }
        ps[i]=4;
        if (i<k)
            k--;

    }
}

// now here yuo can output your data
for(auto&& res : results){
   cout << res << "\n"; // \n to not force flush
}
cout << endl; // now force flush
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, you should also remove the priority increase. It's useless on Windows if your program is the only one who needs CPU time (and impolite if it isn't) because Windows will always give non-waiting programs as much CPU time as it possibly can: It won't keep the CPU idle when there's stuff to do (except possibly on laptops to save battery).

Comment: After removing 'cout' it really started work impressively fast!

Answer (score 1):

What's probably happening is you're on a multi-core/multi-thread machine and you're running on only one thread, the rest of the CPU power is just sitting idle.  So you'll want to multi-thread your code.  Look at boost [thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread.html).